# How do I reset Lubuntu fonts? Fonts are messed up everywhere

Tags: lubuntu, fonts

Hello I tried to install some fonts and I messed up my entire system fonts. All fonts are different than then the default ones. Now, the numbers appear as emojis.
[In Firefox URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmwWF.png)

Even the fonts of VSCode are messed up (I tried resetting them from vscode settings but didn't work)

[In VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZCcR.png)

[In VSCode terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdfWi.png)

Please help me reset my fonts in lubuntu 19.10

Comment: Don't forget your 19.10 release reaches EOL today, so *release-upgrade* asap to Lubuntu 20.04 LTS.  https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce/2020-July/005494.html  https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/D/upgrading.html  As for fixing your fonts, what did you do that mucked them up?  Did you delete fonts? change fonts? as I'd be tempted to reverse whatever you did, and currently we don't know what that was. Partial pictures don't really help, me at least.

Comment: I tried to get color emojis inside of Discord because they just appeared as black and white unicodes. I tried lots of different things, I don't even remember now. And I deleted fonts as well.

Comment: Will updating fix the fonts? kek

Comment: If you used commands, the commands will show in your `history` (*unless you took steps to have them not be recorded*). If you didn't use commands but removed packages, logs will show the changes (/var/log/apt/history.log`)   *Given I don't know what you did, how you changed things, I don't currently know if an upgrade will fix things*

Comment: https://starb.in/ufcXXX.properties Here are some of the things I did for both messing up and trying fixes from the internet. Is there no way to just reset the fonts?

Comment: If your font cache is corrupted, you can rebuild it (`sudo fc-cache -fv` which is useful should you make changes, add/delete etc), however that will not restore any fonts you deleted, you'll have to restore your backups for that purpose. I see the `fc-cache` command in your history though; and see a `rm /etc/fonts/fonts.conf`; for my system that file is found in `fontconfig-config` (ie. I ran `dpkg -S /etc/fonts/fonts.conf` on my later Lubuntu) so a `sudo apt install --reinstall fontconfig-config` should restore that file, but I only quickly scanned your paste.

Comment: The first line printed by `sudo fc-cache -fv` says `Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file` even after `sudo apt install --reinstall fontconfig-config`

Comment: ps:   Modifying your configs so date & time is added to your command `history` I think is well worthwhile in troubleshooting problems...   *they'll be something else I didn't see, but I gotta head to bed*

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it myself.

Go to Preferences => KDE System Settings => Fonts => Then Click `Defaults`

And reboot

If you're still having the problem then, try this:

Go to Preferences => KDE System Settings => Fonts => Font Manage => Then delete or disable `Emoji One` and `EmojiOne Color` fonts. Then reboot.